# How to get records randomly from the Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, select, random

I need to select rows randomly from an Oracle DB.

Ex:  Assume a table with 100 rows, how I can randomly return 20 of those records from the entire 100 rows.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   table
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum < 21;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This will however only select the first 20 rows from the table and order them randomly.

Comment: Ah - I thought you'd have to `INITIALIZE()` in that case.

Comment: You have to be aware that this is a very heavy operation on large tables, because it will first assign a random number to EACH row, then sort on this value and then take some records from it.

Comment: @NishantSharma, the rows are randomised, _then_ limited - your comment isn't correct.

Comment: This approach is VERY slow

Comment: @EvanKroske what alternative approach would you suggest?

Comment: @JonBetts, I think that sample is much faster and more resource-efficient: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920431/156787

Answer (score 68):

[SAMPLE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2105143) is not *guaranteed* to give you exactly 20 rows, but might be suitable (and may perform significantly better than a full query + sort-by-random for large tables):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table SAMPLE(20);
```

Note: the `20` here is an approximate percentage, not the number of rows desired. In this case, since you have 100 rows, to get approximately 20 rows you ask for a 20% sample.

Comment: sample is fast but doesn't appear to be very random.  records towards the top/beginning of the table tend to be favored.

Comment: that'll happen if you stop the query before it gets through the whole table.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, your post is fine and the results are equally distributed.  It's when you add "where rownum <= 20" in combination with sample(20) that the data starts to become less random.

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT * FROM table SAMPLE(10) WHERE ROWNUM <= 20;
```

This is more efficient as it doesn't need to sort the Table.

Comment: Stopping the sample after 20 rows will result in non-random results (rows found earlier in the table will be returned far more often than later ones). Also, this is not guaranteed to return 20 rows.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column, dbms_random.value FROM table ORDER BY 2 )
where rownum <= 20;
```

Answer (score 8):

In case of huge tables standard way with sorting by dbms_random.value is not effective because you need to scan whole table and dbms_random.value is pretty slow function and requires context switches. For such cases, there are 3 additional methods:

---

**1: Use `sample` clause:**

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6

for example:

```sql
select *
from s1 sample block(1)
order by dbms_random.value
fetch first 1 rows only
```

ie get 1% of all blocks, then sort them randomly and return just 1 row.

---

**2: if you have an index/primary key on the column with normal distribution**, you can get min and max values, get random value in this range and get first row with a value greater or equal than that randomly generated value.

Example:

```sql
--big table with 1 mln rows with primary key on ID with normal distribution:
Create table s1(id primary key,padding) as 
   select level, rpad('x',100,'x')
   from dual 
   connect by level<=1e6;

select *
from s1 
where id>=(select 
              dbms_random.value(
                 (select min(id) from s1),
                 (select max(id) from s1) 
              )
           from dual)
order by id
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

---

**3: get random table block, generate rowid and get row from the table by this rowid**:

```sql
select * 
from s1
where rowid = (
   select
      DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_CREATE (
         1, 
         objd,
         file#,
         block#,
         1) 
   from    
      (
      select/*+ rule */ file#,block#,objd
      from v$bh b
      where b.objd in (select o.data_object_id from user_objects o where object_name='S1' /* table_name */)
      order by dbms_random.value
      fetch first 1 rows only
      )
);
```

Comment: the "sample" example is excellent!

Answer (score 6):

In summary, two ways were introduced

```
1) using order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE clause
2) using sample([%]) function
```

The first way has advantage in 'CORRECTNESS' which means you will never fail get result if it actually exists, while in the second way you may get no result even though it has cases satisfying the query condition since information is reduced during sampling.

The second way has advantage in 'EFFICIENT' which mean you will get result faster and give light load to your database.
I was given an warning from DBA that my query using the first way gives loads to the database

You can choose one of two ways according to your interest!

Answer (score 5):

To randomly select 20 rows I think you'd be better off selecting the lot of them randomly ordered and selecting the first 20 of that set.

Something like:

```
Select *
  from (select *
          from table
         order by dbms_random.value) -- you can also use DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
 where rownum < 21;
```

Best used for small tables to avoid selecting large chunks of data only to discard most of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to pick a random sample out of each group:

```
SELECT GROUPING_COLUMN, 
       MIN (COLUMN_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) 
         AS RANDOM_SAMPLE
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY GROUPING_COLUMN
ORDER BY GROUPING_COLUMN;
```

I'm not sure how efficient it is, but if you have a lot of categories and sub-categories, this seems to do the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

-- Q. How to find Random 50% records from table ?

when we want percent wise randomly data

SELECT *
FROM   (
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum <= (select count(*) from table_name) * 50/100;

Comment: if  you want only 20 record randomly then use below query : 

SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT * FROM table_name
 ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
 WHERE rownum <=20;

Answer (score -1):

select *  from
(SELECT * FROM   emp ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM )where
rownum <= 1 ;

Comment: This is just an unformatted copy of the accepted answer with a different table name and a different row number. Please don't repeat answers.