# simple random sampling while pulling data from warehouse(oracle engine) using proc sql in sas

Tags: sampling, sas, oracle

I need to pull humongous amount of data, say 600-700 variables from different tables in a data warehouse...now the dataset in its raw form will easily touch 150 gigs - 79 MM rows and for my analysis purpose I need only a million rows...how can I pull data using proc sql directly from warehouse by doing simple random sampling on the rows.

Below code wont work as  ranuni is not supported by oracle

```
    proc sql outobs =1000000;
    select * from connection to oracle(
    select * from tbl1 order by ranuni(12345);
    quit;
```

How do you propose I do it

Comment: Better to ask on a programming site as it is not clear that you have a statistical question here.

Comment: I know but a lot of us statistical folks can benefit from this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple random sampling while pulling data from warehouse(oracle engine) using proc sql in sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518018/simple-random-sampling-while-pulling-data-from-warehouseoracle-engine-using-pr)

Comment: This is no duplicate, because in the refered question, there were only 100 record in the source table. Here sorting should be avoided.

Comment: @DirkHorsten - perhaps you are referring to this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868409/how-to-get-records-randomly-from-the-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need a sample of about 700 rows. Let us put that in a macro variable *(For those more familiar with other languagues than SAS, that is someting like a precompiler variable.)*

```
%let required_rows = 700;
```

Now calculate what fraction of the data this is (and hope ORACLE does not scan the whole table). Again I put this in a macro variable. *(For those familiar with other languagues, yes SAS has techniques to fill in macro variable while executing the code. That is possible because SAS does stepwise compilation.)*

```
proc sql;
    select &required_rows / rows_tbl1 
    into :required_fraction
    from connection to oracle
    (   select count(*) as rows_tbl1
        from tbl1 );
```

And finaly retreive about that many records

```
    select * from connection to oracle
    (   select *
        from tbl1 
        where DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE < &required_fraction );
quit;
```

**Remarks :**

- I did not test this code.
- If you need exactly 700 rows, you might retreive twice the required fraction and randomly sample in SAS