# Select N arbitrary rows from a very large table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, large-data

I have a very large table `MY_TABLE` (100 million rows). I wish to select a sample of 5, say,  records from this table.

What I can think of is getting 5 arbitrary primary keys as follows, this uses fast full scan as the explain plan shows:

```
select MY_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN from (select MY_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN, rownum as rn from MY_TABLE) where rn <=5
```

and then getting the records corresponding to these primary keys.

However this is still very very slow..

Can it be done more efficiently?

Comment: Have you seen the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868409/how-to-get-records-randomly-from-the-oracle-database. ?

Comment: Why not just `select MY_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN from MY_TABLE where rownum <=5`?

Comment: @defaultlocale the question is not about large tables and glancing, at least superficially, at the answers there, I don't see how these can help me.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9531313800346986113

Comment: As it seems, you don't really care about these rows being uniformly distributed. Have you tried `select * from my_table where rownum <= 5`?

Comment: @defaultlocale no, as I said, this takes a lot of time, whereas the answer which I posted runs almost instantly..

Comment: @JohnDonn This is not normal. Is there anything suspicious in the execution plan of this query? You can also try to add an optimizer hint (e.g. "`select /*+ ALL_ROWS */ column
from my_table
where rownum<=5`"), just in case `rownum` triggers some check in query optimizer.

Comment: I would use a very small block sample e.g. `select * from my_table sample block(1e-6) where rownum <= 5`. This has to scan the whole table but it skips most of the blocks so might complete in an acceptable time.

Comment: @defaultlocale, WilliamRobertson Thank you, as I explained in the edited answer, I simply got confused.

Answer (score 1):

As it looks, I got confused. As the commenters noticed, there should have been no problem with the query

```
select * from MY_TABLE where rownum <=5
```

but I somehow started to look at

```
select MY_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN from (select MY_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN, rownum as rn from MY_TABLE) where rn <=5
```

which indeed runs very slowly..

Sorry for wasting everyone's time, the `select * from MY_TABLE where rownum <=5` works perfectly.

Comment: This is essentially the same as `select * from my_table where rownum <= 5` as suggested earlier, so it's a bit odd that it performs differently.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thank you, you are right; I got confused.