# Trying to select 5 random rows from table as part of testing

Tags: sql, oracle

as part of some testing I am attempting to select 5 random rows from a table, the code I'm running is:

```
select * 
from Table_Name
order by RAND()
Limit 5;
```

Upon executing the code I am presented with the error *SQL command not properly ended*, could someone advise on how to get this working? for reference I am using oracle SQL Developer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Limit doesn't exist in Oracle. You need to use "fetch first 5 rows only" or use rownum or sample. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868409/how-to-get-records-randomly-from-the-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

With sample data like this:

| ID | NAME_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME_FOR_1 |
| 2 | NAME_FOR_2 |
| 3 | NAME_FOR_3 |
| 4 | NAME_FOR_4 |
| 5 | NAME_FOR_5 |
| 6 | NAME_FOR_6 |
| 7 | NAME_FOR_7 |
| 8 | NAME_FOR_8 |
| 9 | NAME_FOR_9 |
| 10 | NAME_FOR_10 |
| 11 | NAME_FOR_11 |
| 12 | NAME_FOR_12 |
| 13 | NAME_FOR_13 |
| 14 | NAME_FOR_14 |
| 15 | NAME_FOR_15 |

You can do it with a nested query:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, NAME_ID
FROM   
    (
        SELECT 
            ID, NAME_ID
        FROM   
            a_table
        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
    )
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 5;
```

... the result will be different every time you run the query...

```sql
/*  Result (one of)
        ID NAME_ID                                         
---------- -------------------------------------------------
        14 NAME_FOR_14                                       
         9 NAME_FOR_9                                        
        13 NAME_FOR_13                                       
        15 NAME_FOR_15                                       
         8 NAME_FOR_8
*/
```

Regards...